# Adding a Date Range

Tags: pdf, date, acrobat

I have an Adobe time sheet where I need to populate all of the date fields based on a beginning date.

For instance if I enter 08-01-11 I need the end date to automatically add 28 days.

Then below, I need all the date fields in the column to list 08-01-11, 08-02-11, etc.  The first and last entry should equal the start date and end date.

I have researched for the last few hours but I am unable to find a solution.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Tom M.

Comment: I am using Adobe Acrobat X.  The document is a .pdf

Answer (score 0):

I did a quick experiment. (I used 7 dates instead of 28 to reduce repetitive work.)

First I created a simple document in Word with a table and some static text labeling the different fields and leaving room for the text fields.

Next, I print to PDF and open the PDF in Acrobat. Here I add 9 text fields. 2 for the start and end dates and 7 for the consecutive dates. I call them startDate, endDate, date1, ..., date7. I set the format of all fields to Date. I make all fields except startDate read-only.

Next, I go the Calculate tab of the endDate field and enter the following JavaScript code (Custom calculatation script):

```
var f = this.getField("startDate");
var d = new Date(f.value);
d.setDate(d.getDate()+6); 
event.value = util.printd("mm/dd/yyyy", d);
```

I do something similar for the date1, ..., date7 fields.

You can download the result here:
http://download.tallcomponents.com/timesheet.pdf

Frank Rem, http://www.tallcomponents.com

Comment: I just opened the PDF in Chrome. The Chrome built-in viewer does not interpret the JavaScript correctly :-( Save the PDF to disk and open with a PDF reader (e.g. the free Adobe PDF Reader).

Comment: I'm doing this one step at a time.  When I add the script I am getting the following error:  Invalid date/time:  please ensure that the date/time exists.  Field [TO] should match format mm/dd/yy.  I adjusted the field format and the script and I still get the message.

Comment: Ok.  I figured out what is happening.  You have to enter the date exactly as formatted.  I get the same message, however, when I reset the form.  Every line gives the same error.

Comment: Is there a way to add a line that tells the script not to run if the field it is looking to calculate on is preceded by a NULL value?  Fore example, if I reset the form and it resets the Start Date, then the rest of the fields will not process?

Comment: I added a Reset button to my form and was able to reproduce your problem. What you can do to solve this is to exclude all date fields (so also the start date) from the Reset action. You can do this by selecting the Resest action and pushing the Edit button and then unchecking all date fields.

Comment: One other question, for giggles.  There is an area in the form where you put what type of day you have.  For instance 3-11, X, S.  Is there a way to use JS to calculate the total hours based on those entries?  IF [FIELD1]= '3-11' then VAL=8 ELSE IF [FIELD1]= 'x' THE VAL=0,  etc.  Is there a way I can send my form to you so you can see what I am referring to?

Comment: It should now be obvious how to read values from fields and how to assign values to fields. The calculation/parsing in between is a general programming problem. I will leave that up to you :-) The Acrobat JavaScript Scripting Guide is a good place to start:
partners.adobe.com/public/developer/en/acrobat/sdk/AcroJSGuide.pdf